# How Persistence Unit works in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to learn JPA with Hibernate implementation. There are lot of blog of net about this but still i am struggling to implement it. I have written one Dao class which creates the `EntityManagerFactory`. But while looking this `PERSISTENCE_UNIT` it says

> `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named test`

```
private final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "test";
private EntityManager entityManager;


public GenericDao() {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
    entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();

}
```

I also created one persistence.xml file which is in META-INF folder of web application. It looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgres://localhost:1532/test" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

For deployment Tomcat8 is being used. Please let me know why application not able to lookup `PERSISTENCE_UNIT`.

Comment: Do you have persistence.xml in your output .war file (in `/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF `)? Is `hibernate-entitymanager` on the classpath?

Comment: Tomcat is not a regular application server; may be you should try it on Java EE complaint Application servers.

Comment: hibernate-entitymanager is in class path but in war file persistence.xml file in app/META-INF folder not in /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF.

Comment: @Rai.skumar, yes Tomcat is not regular application server. But this example should be worked on Tomcat too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment - the problem is your persistence.xml location. It needs to be exactly where your application expects it to be:

```
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml
```

Now, why did you encounter this problem is another matter, connected with how you create your .war file. Solution that should work however, is trusting Maven to take care of that. If you set packaging to `war`, and  put your META-INF folder into resources (`src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`) it should take care of things.